# Cover in latex problem to setting a vertical rule

Tags: rules, covers

I am using the example posted by [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5ccc81f4b95406669496b6e3) to create my cover. When I add more items I have the following problems: (1) two pages instead of one cover page and (2) the vertical rule is misaligned.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} % A4 paper size and default 12pt font size

\usepackage{graphicx}
% Set figures path
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}

\newcommand*{\plogo}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,scale=0.1]{winterfell.png}} % Generic dummy publisher logo

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{stix} % Use the STIX fonts

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage} % Suppresses displaying the page number on the title page and the subsequent page counts as page 1

    \raggedleft % Right align the title page

    \rule{1pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
    \hspace{0.05\textwidth} % Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
    \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{ % Paragraph box for holding the title page text, adjust the width to move the title page left or right on the page

        {\Huge\bfseries Kolkata Paise} \\
        [0.5\baselineskip] 
        {\Huge\bfseries {Restaurant (v2)}}\\
        [4\baselineskip]
        {\Large\textbf{University of WinterFell}}\\
        [0.5\baselineskip]
        {\Large\textbf{Degree in Night's Watch}}\\
        [0.5\baselineskip]
        {\Large\textbf{Exam in white walkers peacekeeper}}\\
        [4\baselineskip]
        {\Large\textsc{Jon Snow}} \\
        [1\baselineskip]
        {\large\textsc{Id: 1234567}}\\
        [0.5\baselineskip]
        {\large email: \textit{jon.snow@alumni.winterfell.edu}}\\

        \vspace{0.5\textheight} % Whitespace between the title block and the publisher
        \begin{center}
            {\noindent \plogo}\\[\baselineskip] % Publisher and logo
        \end{center}

    }

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is probably because you know nothing ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lord Snow needs to learn that by using `\\` to break lines he is helping the Underfull King on his quest to bring the Long Misalignment upon the realm of the living. He may have the entire army of TeXeros at his side, but without blades forged using `\par` he has no chance against the Underfull King.

A man would advise Lord Snow to avoid using rigid spacing, like `\vspace{4\baselineskip}` (unless it is question of life and death) and use `\vfill` instead, so the space is filled as necessary. Multiple `\vfill`s can be used to get more space between two elements.

> [image]

Here's the Working code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} % A4 paper size and default 12pt font size

\usepackage{graphicx}
% Set figures path
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}

\newcommand*{\plogo}{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,scale=0.1]{winterfell.png}} % Generic dummy publisher logo

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{stix} % Use the STIX fonts

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage} % Suppresses displaying the page number on the title page and the subsequent page counts as page 1
    \raggedleft % Right align the title page
    \rule{1pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
    \hspace{0.05\textwidth}% Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
    \parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{% Paragraph box for holding the title page text, adjust the width to move the title page left or right on the page
        \Huge
          \bfseries
            Kolkata Paise\par
            Restaurant (v2)\par
        \vspace{4\baselineskip}
        \Large
            University of WinterFell\par
        \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
            Degree in Night's Watch\par
            Exam in white walkers peacekeeper\par
        \vspace{4\baselineskip}
          \scshape
            Jon Snow\par
        \vspace{1\baselineskip}
            Id: 1234567\par
        \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}
        \large
          \normalfont
            email: \textit{jon.snow@alumni.winterfell.edu}
        \par
        \vfill
        % Whitespace between the title block and the publisher
        \centering
          \noindent\plogo
        \vspace*{0.5\baselineskip}
    }
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

And remember: What do we say to the God of MS Word?

Comment: NOT TODAY!!! ;)